# Difference between available, free and cached in free command

Tags: free

What is the difference between available memory and free memory. Is available memory and cached memory are same. If not, what's the difference. I have referred some answers and they says available memory is easy to convert to used memory than free memory. So system keeps free memory as low. But my doubt is that, in that case why i have to clear cache to make my application run.

Comment: Related: [What does -/+ buffers/cache means in the output of free?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/185251)

Comment: Also: [Is "Cached" memory de-facto free?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/499649)

Comment: You might have seen the linked questions already. Could you [edit] your question to expand on the behaviour you’re seeing with your application? What error messages do you get, what commands do you run to investigate and fix the problem?